# Join query giving empty result SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL learner here, trying to make a join, but it seems to not work.

I have the following 2 tables:

1. [#device_combined_players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9t58.png)
2. [#final_results2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECkBm.png)

The goal is to have a new table **replacing** the **player_store_id** from **#final_results** with the **pseudo_name** from **#device_combined_players**.

I have tried with:

```
SELECT #final_results2.player_store_id,
#device_combined_players.pseudo_name, #final_results2.genre FROM #device_combined_players INNER JOIN #final_results2 ON #final_results2.player_store_id = #device_combined_players.store_id
```

but I can't make it work, my **output** is simply an **empty table**.

Could you guys, please,  give me some light? Thank you!

My **expected result** would be: as #final_results2 (image 2), but replacing player_store_id column by pseudo_name from #device_combined_players table.

EDIT: a screenshot with more details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSyLb.png

Comment: can you share the output you get and the output you want?

Comment: # in mysql comments out the rest of the line..are you sure you aren't working from/on sql-server/mssql.

Comment: I am on sql-server/mssql, correct. Modified the tag already. Here you can have a summary in a single screenshot; https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSyLb.png

Comment: @lemon, the above link should clarify it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

And, I am answering myself, since I had 2 different issues here. Both are rookie mistakes, but I will leave them here so it helps somebody else in the future:

1. Take a look at the data type of your columns. They can cause conflicts if they are not the same as the columns you are referencing in a JOIN.
2. Check if your data doesn't have spaces. You can use TRIM and LEN to help you out answering this.

I sorted my problem like that.